# A clear, simple explanation of what a struct is in C

Tags: c, struct

I already have somewhat of an idea, but I thought it would be good to get some input from the wonderful people here at sof.

Please let me know if my question is too broad or vague.

Comment: Wikipedia seems ok to me http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct

Comment: It is too broad indeed. If you have an idea, then you should ask about what exactly is still unclear to you. Provided that it hasn't been asked before, that is.

Comment: Why do you ask this? Every decent C book or tutorial will answer this question.

Comment: @paldepind - Any question that meets our FAQ standards and is not a duplicate is welcome on Stack Overflow. @Eric - your question is a little broad. Perhaps you could add what you presume a structure to be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is a bit broad, but...

A struct is an *aggregate* or *composite* data type, used for representing entities that are described by multiple *attributes* of potentially different types.  Some examples:

- A point in 3-D space, represented by 3 real-valued coordinates x, y, and z;
- A mailing address, represented by a street name, house or apartment number, city, state, ZIP code;
- A line item in an invoice, represented by a part name or number, unit cost, quantity, and subtotal;
- A node in a tree, represented by a key, data value, left child, and right child;

etc., etc., etc.

Let's look at the mailing address as a concrete example.  We could define our mailing address type as follows:

```
struct Address {
  char *streetName; 
  int buildingNumber;  // House, apt building, office building, etc.    
  char *aptNumber;     // Handles apt and suite #s like K103, B-2, etc.
  char *city;
  char state[3];
  int zip;
};
```

We'd create an instance of that struct like so:

```
struct Address newAddress;
```

and a pointer to that instance as:

```
struct Address *addrPtr = &newAddress;
```

and access each of its fields using either the `.` or `->` operator depending on whether we're dealing with a struct instance or a pointer to a struct:

```
newAddress.streetName = strdup("Elm");
addrPtr->buildingNumber = 100;
...
```

Another way to look at structs is something like a database *record* composed of multiple *fields*.

Answer (score 6):

It's a custom memory layout with human-readable aliases for the offsets within the memory area.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the most simple explanation, but for completeness, here's what the standard has to say about structures (C99 6.2.5 §20):

> A structure type describes a
>   sequentially allocated nonempty set of
>   member objects (and, in certain
>   circumstances, an incomplete array),
>   each of which has an optionally
>   specified name and possibly distinct
>   type.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN -

A structure type is a user-defined composite type. It is composed of fields or members that can have different types.